# How can I convert a java String to map?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to convert this below format file into map "key,value" pair variable.
How can I do this?

cat 10
hen 10
cat 10
gun 10
hen 10
lion 10
owl 10
pig 10

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle the repeated keys.

Comment: @AndersonVieira I want to map the value with the key ie cat with 10, hen with 10 etc. Basically I am trying to do a reduce. Above is the output of my map function.

Comment: Is the string is single string variable or list/array of strings ? so basically you want `cat as key and 10 as a value` ? right ?

Comment: @ASP You have two entries for the key `cat`. What do you want to do when you try to insert the second entry? Ignore it, sum the values, or something else?

Comment: @user3145373ツ yes, that is exactly how I want it to be. It is a single string. When the next cat occurs, I want to add the value 10 and 10, so key cat will have value 20.

Comment: @AndersonVieira I apologize for not being very clear. I want to add the value 10 and 10, so key cat will have value 20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to add the values for repeated keys, you could use `Map.merge()`.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, **replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function**, or removes if the result is null. **This method may be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key**.

For example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String seq = "cat 10 hen 10 cat 10 gun 10 hen 10 lion 10 owl 10 pig 10";

    // [cat, 10, hen, 10, cat, 10, gun, 10, hen, 10, lion, 10, owl, 10, pig, 10]
    String[] splitEntries = seq.split(" ");

    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitEntries.length - 1; i += 2) {
        // Iterate on splitEntries incrementing i by 2, so we can store the pairs:
        // (0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), etc.
        String key = splitEntries[i];
        Integer value = Integer.valueOf(splitEntries[i + 1]);
        // Pass Integer::sum so the previous value will be summed with the new one
        // when trying to insert a repeated key
        myMap.merge(key, value, Integer::sum);
    }
    System.out.println(myMap);
}
```

Output:

```
{hen=20, gun=10, owl=10, cat=20, lion=10, pig=10}
```

If you can not use Java 8, instead of calling `myMap.merge()`, you could check if there is already a value stored for the given `key`. If there isn't, just make `previousValue = 0` and sum it to the new `value`.

```
Integer previousValue = myMap.get(key);
if (previousValue == null) {
    previousValue = 0;
}
myMap.put(key, previousValue + value);
```

Note that this is not thread-safe, though. Another thread could, for example, update the map after you call `get()` but before you call `put()`, resulting in the wrong value being stored. If this is a concern, you could put this code within a `synchronized` block.

Comment: I do not have the merge method. I guess its the java version problem, if I am not wrong. What should I do for this?

Comment: @ASP Yes, it is available only for Java 8. I will update the answer with an example in Java 7, but you should really consider updating to Java 8 if you can.

Comment: Yes, I will surely update this. Although I need this code for to run on a virtual machine which has java 7 in it. So I will have to stick to those methods.

Comment: For the method before JDK 8, you should mention that it is not a thread-safe.

Comment: @AdrianShum Good point. I don't think the Java 8 version is thread-safe, though. From the `Map.merge()` documentation: "The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties.". The `HashMap` implementation documentation says nothing about it and I see no `synchronized` block in the code, so I assume it's not thread-safe either. If this is a concern, I think the OP should probably use `ConcurrentHashMap` in both cases.

Comment: I should be more clear: The JDK <=7 logic is not thread-safe EVEN you are using a thread-safe implementation.  You can wrap the whole logic in synchronized (in case of using sychronized map impl) or there is no obvious way to solve (if you are using ConcurrentHashMap)

Comment: @AdrianShum I see what you mean. I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for the observation!